# Using findElement in groovy pages

Tags: groovy, geb

Apologies if this question seems trivial,.. but I am very very new to groovy/selenium as part of a maven system I’ve been thrown at and am in need to understand what I am missing in trying to get this method to work.

The error I am getting is below:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: GebConfig.findElement() is applicable for argument types: (org.openqa.selenium.By$ByName)
```

I’m in need to locate elements on a web page and would like to use the findElement method, however my code is in groovy as part of step definitions.
I have ended up with the following after lots of attempts but am getting nowhere:

```
package step_definitions
import features.support.Requests

import geb.*
import org.apache.commons.io.*
import org.openqa.selenium.By
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
import org.openqa.selenium.*
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.*
import cucumber.api.groovy.EN.*

When(~/^find the element named "(.*?)"$/) { String btnName ->
WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.name(btnName));
}
```

I know I can use things like the below for a button and similar for other things like radio buttons and input fields:

```
browser.$(‘input’, name: ‘btnK’)
$(‘input’, name: ‘btnK’)
```

But I’d prefer to know how to use the findElement approach.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Jim…..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you are using Geb with Cucumber JVM. If you've setup your environment using `geb.binding.BindingUpdater` as described in http://gebish.org/manual/current/#writing-your-own-steps then the methods and properties available in your steps are as listed in http://gebish.org/manual/current/#browser-methods-and-properties. You will notice that there is no `driver` property in that list - if you wish to access the driver instance then you will have to obtain it from `browser`:

```
When(~/^find the element named "(.*?)"$/) { String myName ->
    WebElement myElement = browser.driver.findElement(By.name(btnName));
}
```

Comment: I wasn't using geb.binding.BindingUpdater and none (the few that I tried were go/waitFor) of those shortcuts as listed on your 2nd link worked. I'll look at adjusting how the browser gets started and report back. By the sounds of it if those shortcut commands work then the suggestion you provided would probably also work.

Comment: Much closer now,.. previous comment was supposed to be to/waitFor didn't work,.. but 'go' did. I'm now able to locate an element with the oneliner you provided - the bit I was missing was getting the driver instance from browser. Am I able to make the findElement statement work with an assert ?

Comment: Went with a try/catch approach which seemed to work. Had also tried it last night, but must have messed up something before I commented above.